# How can patches/changesets be composed using SVN on a per-line basis?

Tags: svn, patch

Using SVN it is fairly easy to compose a patch/changeset off a working copy containing many changes on a per-file basis. Such functionality is covered by Eclipse clients like the command line client, Subclipse or TortoiseSVN.

Is there a way to do this on a per-line level?

This would be useful if you are working on two bug fixes in parallel which effect the same file but you want to create two patches/commits out of this file.

A possible but cumbersome workaround would be to use a second working copy as a staging area.

Answer (score 0):

Not really. You could split the patch by hand and apply one at a time to a fresh working copy but that's kind of kludgey if you ask me. A better way would be to create two branches; one for bug fix A and one for big fix B.